# Cordova TalkBack Issues

Tags: android, cordova, accessibility

I am developing an Cordova application and am working on making it accessible. In iOS, VoiceOver works fine and as you would expect with a native application. For Android, TalkBack briefly works on the first screen of the application. After the first screen, TalkBack stops responding (globally, not just in the application) and will not allow the user to swipe to the next element, or select any elements.

The content is build using all the right ARIA tags and following the specs, Android and TalkBack just doesn't seem to be playing nicely with HTML content and WebView.

The application is targeting Android 4.3 and Android 4.4.

Can anyone point to a Cordova / PhoneGap application that works properly with TalkBack on Android?

Comment: I am also facing the issue in 5.0.2 with HTML5 phonegap app. Issue is filed in https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=130&sort=-id but not seeing the fix for the same. Please let me know if you are able to solve